# Combining two text files into third one and keeping track of data

Tags: c

I've run into a problem solution to which I can't find.

I'm combining two text files into a third one and I want to keep track of the data I'm moving. So far, the code does one thing and absolutely ignores other.

Here is the code:

```
// enable standard c i/o functions
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    // Open two files to be merged
    FILE *fp1 = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("test2.txt", "r");

    // Open file to store the result
    FILE *fp3 = fopen("results.txt", "w+");
    char c; 
    int count2ch = 0; // count meter for characters
    int count1ch = 0; // count meter for characters
    int totalch = 0; // holds number of total ammount of characters
    int count1wd = 0; // count meter for words
    int count2wd = 0; // count meter for words
    int totalWD = 0;// holds total ammount of words

    // Check files
    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not open file");
        exit(0);
    }


    // COUNTING CHARACTERS
    // count characters file one
    while (1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp1);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        count1ch++;
    }
    // count characters file two
    while (1)
    {
        c = fgetc(fp2);
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        count2ch++;
    }

    //MERGING FILES
    // Copy contents of first file to file3.txt
    while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, fp3);
    // Copy contents of second file to file3.txt
    while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, fp3);


    // COUNTING WORDS
    //count words file one
    while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            count1wd++;
    }
    //count words file two
    while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            count2wd++;
    }

    // count total ammount of words
    totalWD = count1wd + count2wd;
    // count total ammount of characters
    totalch = count1ch + count2ch;

    printf("Merged file1.txt and file2.txt into file3.txt \n");
    printf("Total number of characters moved: %d\n", totalch);
    printf("The ammount of chars in your first file is :  %d\n", count1ch);
    printf("The ammount of chars in your second file is :  %d\n", count2ch);
    printf("Total number of words moved: %d\n", totalWD);
    printf("The ammount of words in your fist file is : %d\n", count1wd);
    printf("The ammount of words in your second file is : %d\n", count2wd);
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it just combines two files into the third one and that's it. If I move the counting words or characters section above the merging section, the code will do whatever comes first.

Comment: You need to `fseek` back to the beginning of the file. After each set of `fgetc` calls complete as they leave the file pointer at the end of the file.

Comment: As kaylum said, keep track of your file pointers. As soon as you run through the entire file first, `rewind()`. We need to not kill out that functions only use :( Sure `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` does work, but it isn't nearly as beautiful as `rewind(fp)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code refined. The only differences are simplified variable names, the print statements moved to a function, and most importantly, the addition of the `rewind()` function to rewind your file pointers after use. The formatting is also my style, so if you want to change that then feel free.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printCtrs(int, int, int, int, int, int);

void printCtrs(int ttlCh, int c1ch, int c2ch, int ttlWD, int c1wd, int c2wd){
    printf("Merged file1.txt and file2.txt into file3.txt \n");
    printf("Total number of characters moved: %d\n", ttlCh);
    printf("The ammount of chars in your first file is :  %d\n", c1ch);
    printf("The ammount of chars in your second file is :  %d\n", c2ch);
    printf("Total number of words moved: %d\n", ttlWD);
    printf("The ammount of words in your fist file is : %d\n", c1wd);
    printf("The ammount of words in your second file is : %d\n", c2wd);
}

int main(){

    // Open files for reading/writing
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
    fp1 = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("test2.txt", "r");
    fp3 = fopen("results.txt", "w+");

    // Declaring counters
    char c; 
    int     ttlCh = 0, c1ch = 0, c2ch = 0, 
        ttlWD = 0, c1wd = 0, c2wd = 0;

    // If any files fail to open, abort
    if (fp1 == NULL){
        puts("Could not open file fp1");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (fp2 == NULL){
        puts("Could not open file fp2");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (fp3 == NULL){
        puts("Could not open file fp3");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Read through files 1 and 2 and count characters
    while (c = fgetc(fp1) != EOF){ c1ch++; }
    rewind(fp1);    // Reset file pointer 1 to start of file
    while (c = fgetc(fp2) != EOF){ c2ch++; }
    rewind(fp2);    // Reset file pointer 2 to start of file

    // Write file 1 and 2 to 3
    while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF){ fprintf(fp3, "%c", c); }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF){ fprintf(fp3, "%c", c); }

    // Count total words in 1 and 2
    while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){ c1wd++; }
    }
    while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){ c2wd++; }
    }

    ttlWD = c1wd + c2wd;
    ttlCh = c1ch + c2ch;

    // Print counters
    printCtrs(ttlCh, c1ch, c2ch, ttlWD, c1wd, c2wd);

    // Close all files after use
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);

    return 0;
}
```